# Get the current position of a played movie (MPMoviePlayerController currentPlaybackTime doesn't work)

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

hopefully someone has an answer - I am searching now for hours.
I want to get the position of an movie.

I tried it with MPMoviePlayerController, but this class doesn't support the MPMediaPlayback property called "currentPlaybackTime".
(the funny thing is, that the MP **Music** PlayerController has this property)

Therefore I can't get the position in my video. Is there another way to do it???

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MPMoviePlayerController conforms to the MPMediaPlayback protocol, and does have a currentPlaybackTime property available. However, I believe that the currentPlaybackTime property was introduced in 3.2, so it may not be available to you if you're trying to develop on a pre-3.2 device.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. I am working on iOS 4.1. The MPMoviePlayerController conforms to the MPMediaPlayback Protocol, but it doesn't include the currentPlaybackTime property! This is the problem :-( . Or do I have to implement it myself somehow?

Comment: Forget about my last comment. MPMoviePlayerController and the property "currentPlaybackTime" is the right way to do it, even if it is not obviously written as a property in the MPMoviePlayerController.h file... I now get the time in seconds as a float value. thanks

Comment: its not shown on the MPMoviePlayerController.h file because it is in the protocol. You can look at it like inheritance... An MPMoviePlayerController isa MPMediaPlayback object. Meaning it inherits (implements in this case) all of the properties required by the MPMediaPlayBack protocol.