# MPMoviePlayerController | How to play part of Video

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using MPMoviePlayerController to play video. I want to play part of video on clicking play button. For example if my video is of 200 seconds, i want to play video from 50th-100th second. Even i'm not able to get time-length video played at particular instance like at the time of pausing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MPMoviePlayerController` has two properties: `initialPlaybackTime` and `endPlaybackTime` that you can set to an `NSTimeInterval` (= double used to specify a time interval in seconds) to control the start and end time for the playback of the movie.
This code for example will play the movie from the 10th second to the 20th second:

```
[moviePlayerController setInitialPlaybackTime:10.f];
[moviePlayerController setEndPlaybackTime:20.f];
```

Comment: Can we time-length spent on some button click.

Comment: Right now i'm using NSTimer to fulfill my purpose.

Comment: But i'm facing lots of challenge in it. I want to give user the provision of playing part of video again by selecting the time interval....You can say in other way i'm giving provision to record video from playing video.

Comment: Got Solution to my question above: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945796/get-the-current-position-of-a-played-movie-mpmovieplayercontroller-currentplayb